# State is updated but component is not getting Re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using MUI card to display all the posts of logged in user. The MUI card has property of expand or collapse depending upon `true` or `false`. On each card I am giving key `expanded` which is set to empty string initially. On click of icon I am setting `expanded` of that particular post to non-empty string. If expanded field is non-empty string then I am setting true in collapse else false.

The state is getting updated as expected but component is not getting re-render and as a result expand or collapse is not working.

On initial render I am setting the post state and adding expanded field to it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let parr = [];
    const unsub = database.posts
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        parr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let data = { ...doc.data(), postId: doc.id, expanded: "" };
          parr.push(data);
        });
        setPosts(parr);
      });
    return unsub;
}, []);
```

Function called `handleComment` is responsible for setting `expanded` to empty string or non-empty string.

```
  const handleComment = (id) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      if (posts[i].pId === id) {
        if (posts[i].expanded === "") posts[i].expanded = id;
        else posts[i].expanded = "";
      }
    }
    setPosts(posts);
    console.log(posts);
  };
```

A `useEffect` is set on posts which should be called whenever there is change posts state. But it is not getting called.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("re render");
  }, [posts]);
```

Complete code:

```
export default function Posts({ userData }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const getDate = (date) => {
    let seconds = date.seconds + date.nanoseconds / 1000000000;
    let newDate = new Date(seconds * 1000);
    return (
      newDate.getDate() +
      " " +
      newDate.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" })
    );
  };

  const handleComment = (id) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      if (posts[i].pId === id) {
        if (posts[i].expanded === "") posts[i].expanded = id;
        else posts[i].expanded = "";
      }
    }
    setPosts(posts);
    console.log(posts);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("re render");
  }, [posts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("here");
    let parr = [];
    const unsub = database.posts
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        parr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let data = { ...doc.data(), postId: doc.id, expanded: "" };
          parr.push(data);
        });
        setPosts(parr);
      });
    return unsub;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "55%" }}>
      {!posts || userData == null ? (
        <CircularProgress />
      ) : (
        <div className="video-container">
          {posts && posts.map((post, index) => {
            console.log(post);
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} className="card-class">
                  <CardHeader
                    avatar={
                      <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={userData.profileUrl} />
                    }
                    action={
                      <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                        <MoreVertIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    }
                    title={userData.fullname}
                    subheader={getDate(post.createdAt)}
                  />
                  <Video src={post.pURL} />
                  <CardActions disableSpacing>
                    <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                      <Like userData={userData} postData={post} />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={() => handleComment(post.pId)}
                      aria-label="comment"
                      aria-expanded={post.expanded !== "" ? true : false}
                    >
                      <ChatBubbleIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </CardActions>
                  <Collapse
                    in={post.expanded !== "" ? true : false}
                    timeout="auto"
                    unmountOnExit
                  >
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
                      <Typography paragraph>
                        Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add
                        saffron and set aside for 10 minutes.
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography paragraph>
                        Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large,
                        deep skillet over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp
                        and chorizo, and cook, stirring occasionally until
                        lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes. Transfer shrimp to a
                        large plate and set aside, leaving chicken and chorizo
                        in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic, tomatoes,
                        onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring often until
                        thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add saffron
                        broth and remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a
                        boil.
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography paragraph>
                        Add rice and stir very gently to distribute. Top with
                        artichokes and peppers, and cook without stirring, until
                        most of the liquid is absorbed, 15 to 18 minutes. Reduce
                        heat to medium-low, add reserved shrimp and mussels,
                        tucking them down into the rice, and cook again without
                        stirring, until mussels have opened and rice is just
                        tender, 5 to 7 minutes more. (Discard any mussels that
                        don&apos;t open.)
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes,
                        and then serve.
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Collapse>
                </Card>
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also tried using `forEach` and here posts is getting updated and component is getting re-rendered but posts are not getting displayed. Only `CircularProgress` is moving.

```
  const handleComment = (id) => {
    let newPosts = [...posts]
    newPosts = posts.forEach((post) => {
      if(post.pId===id)
      {
        if(post.expanded==="") post.expanded=id;
        else post.expanded="";
      }
    })
    setPosts(newPosts);
    console.log(posts);
  };
```

I tried setting expanded to non-empty string if it is empty string using `handleComment` function. It is working fine but the component is not getting re-render as a result `expanded` remains empty string.

And in the second case of `forEach` posts state is getting updated and component is also getting re-rendered but only CircularProgress is moving and posts are not getting displayed.

Comment: Are u getting any error or warning in your console @Mohd Arsalan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not updating because you're mutating the `posts` array instead of creating a new one. As far as `setPosts()` is concerned you've passed it the same array so there's no re-render needed (see [Updating Arrays in State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)). You could use `map()` to create a new array and perform the logic at the same time.

```js
const handleComment = (id) => {
  setPosts(posts.map(post => {
    if (post.pId === id) {
      return {
        ...post,
        expanded: post.expanded ? "" : id
      }
    } else {
      return post
    }
  }))
};
```

Comment: I have tried to create new array and then update posts using `forEach`. In this case posts state is updating and re-render is also taking place but I only get to see the `CircularProgress` and not posts. See the last code that I have added of `handleComment`.

Comment: @MohdArsalan In your updated code try replacing `newPosts = posts.forEach` with `newPosts.forEach`. Otherwise you're still mutating `posts` and setting `newPosts` to `undefined`